# Pivot multiple rows (2 columns) into a single row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table where it has only 2 columns, the first columns is a name identifier and the second column is a value for this identifier (basically the table acts as default values), below is a screenshot of that table.

[image: default value table]

What I want is to convert the table from multiple rows into a single row and the values would be columns with the first column as column name. Example, the current values to be transformed into the below.

[image: expected result]

I read about the PIVOT operator, however it requires an aggregate function in the pivot clause but I don't think I can use an aggregate function in this case, its just setting row values as column values.
Is this possible with PIVOT or is there another construct I should use to achieve this?

Comment: "...but I don't think I can use an aggregate function..." -- It depends on the quality of the real data. What do you want the query to do, for example, if the data included two rows for `AGE` with different values (such as `42` and `55`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pivot clause for that purpose, like below (Your table has only 2 columns and I assume you don't have any duplicate code)

```sql
select *
from Yourtable
pivot (
max(value) for code in (
        'AGE' as AGE
    ,   'FIRST_NAME' as FIRST_NAME
    ,   'LAST_NAME' as LAST_NAME
    ,   'STATUS' as STATUS
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already a correct technical answer, showing how to pivot in your case.

Let me explain why this "pivoting" is indeed an aggregation, at a logical level.

You have a group of four rows, and you want to generate a "summary row" for the group. (Imagine, in parallel, that you had several employees identified by employee id, in an additional column; each employee had up to four rows, for the same attributes. Then you are grouping by employee id, each group has up to four rows - fewer if there are missing attributes - and you want to get a "summary row" for each group.)

This is a form of aggregation. But for what aggregate function? You seem to only have one value for `AGE`, only one value for `STATUS`, etc.

In fact, you can think of `AGE` as existing in each of the four rows. When the `CODE` is `'AGE'` then the value is `42`, and when the `CODE` is something else then the value is `NULL`. You could use `SUM()`, `AVG()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()` over these four values (one is `42`, the rest are `NULL`); they would all return the same answer, `42` - since all aggregate functions ignore `NULL`.

What if the values are strings, not numbers? Answer: same thing - except you can't use `SUM()` or `AVG()`. You still have `MIN()` and `MAX()`. In fact you could use other aggregate function too - they just have to be string aggregates. For example you could use `LISTAGG()`. Again, you are aggregating a single non-`NULL` string, the others are `NULL`, so the result will be just that one non-`NULL` string.

Before Oracle introduced the `PIVOT` operator in version 11.1 of the database, programmers were already able to pivot - using a conditional aggregation just like I explained. Something like

```
select max(case when code = 'AGE' then AGE end) as AGE,
       ...
from   ...
group  by EMPLOYEE_ID   -- in the more general case
```

(in your simple case you don't need to group by anything.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation mathguy, I get now how it works with max function and string values.